# Algorithm for text based different distance calculation or fingerprint

Tags: c++, algorithm, text, hash, fingerprinting

So, I have a TON of .txt files,(several gigabytes) and I'm hoping to organize them and have some method for finding near duplicates and edits.

**Is there an algorithm, that can read a text file, and produce a sort of hash or fingerprint of the text, that so the more edits or additions a block of text has, the farther its hamming distance is from the given fingerprint/hash?**

For instance: Given any length of text, id live to produce a value of some N length. that can be used to check for similarity between other text documents.

So: For N=8

```
"Some text bla bla bla bla bla ext."   => "21juob1G"
"Other text of different length"       => "fejbweoi"
"Close text bla bla bla bla bla ext."  => "f2juob1G"
```

Between example 1 and 3, the Outputs are similar enough chat I can calculate a hamming distance and determine that given texts are EXTREMELY similar.

**Trying to build this in C++. Does this exist?**

Iv looked into plagiarism algorithms, and see some promise, but I cant find any that have a nice example or an algorithm description I can replicate.

My current approach right now, is to just strip all non characters from a given text, divide it into 32 equal sized blocks, and compute a sum of all the letters as numbers then sigmoid that result into a single byte. But i'm getting results that are... Too similar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing in general and nilsimsa in particular might be relevant

Comment: See: [tag:edit-distance] [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/levenshtein-distance/info) and [tag:levenshtein-distance] [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/levenshtein-distance/info)